# Adding a id to to link to a class

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi guys I am trying to add an id to a link so that it can produce some content. For example I have a button which when clicked will show a div with text inside of it. That div is hidden, This works perfectly, I want to try and reproduce this using anther button with an icon this time but for some reason I cant get it to work at all:

For my button to work all I needed to do was have :

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="header2">Reklambyrå</button>
```

The ID was linked to some JS which showed me the content : 
**JS:**

```
$("#header1").click(function() {
  $("#section_one").fadeToggle(2000);
  $("#section_two").fadeOut(1000);
});
```

This works fine but when I put this html in:

```
<div class="sidebar-social">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" title="Facebook" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" id="header1">
                <i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>
                <span id="header1">facebook</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="URL-HERE" title="Twitter" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i><span>twitter</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now I want the facebook icon to link to the same content as the button but I cant seem to get it to work at all, Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: can you please make a working snippet with the relevant/minimum code needed to reproduce your problem ? you are missing some html and maybe css from your question. make it in a working code snippet here on SO

Comment: you have repeated the `id="header1"` in your code which might be the reson for it to not work as you can have only 1 id with same value

Comment: Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lu5efy9o/

Comment: You can see the first button works fine but i want the facebook button 2 do the same thing

Comment: Just in case my English is bad, my first button works perfectly gets me the content up, i want the Facebook button to do the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have more that 1 element with id `#header1` which causes the script only to work for the first `#header1` which is the button. You are not allowed to have duplicate ids, so i changed the id's.

You should use a class that is common to the elements you want to click. For example add class `.clickME` to the button and `.clickME` to the `a` Facebook.

Or if you have only one id with `#header1` then just use that.

Then in the click function add `.preventDefault()` so the  link won't follow the href but instead do what you intended it to do

```js
$("#header1").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault()
      $("#section_one").fadeToggle(2000);
      $("#section_two").fadeOut(1000);
    });
    $("#header2").click(function() {
      $("#section_two").fadeToggle(2000);
      $("#section_one").fadeOut(1000);
    });
```

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/


/* Optional theme */

@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.parallax1 {
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 33px;
  display: none;
}

.sidebar-social {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-social ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sidebar-social li {
  text-align: center;
  width: 15.9%;
  margin-bottom: 3px!important;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sidebar-social i {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #383533;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.sidebar-social a {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-social a span {
  color: black;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 5px 0 10px 0;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.sidebar-social a:hover i.fa-paint-brush {
  color: #FFC600;
}

.sidebar-social a:hover i.fa-mobile {
  color: #FFC600
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="sidebar-social">

      <ul>
        <li>
          <!--    Problem here  -->
          <a href="#" title="Facebook" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="clickME" id="header1"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush" id="header1"></i>
      <span id="header1span">facebook</span></a></li>
        <!--     -->

        <li><a href="URL-HERE" title="Twitter" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i><span>twitter</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<div class="parallax1" id="section_one">
  <div class="row newtryh2">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 middlethat">
      <h2>WiFi via Facebook</h2><span class="border"></span>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont think i explained my self well enough, I just want to get the facebook button working like the first button , i will delete my first button i just want the facebook one in, but everytime i click it , a new page pops up because i have the a tag, so i want to get rid of that and put the ID in if that makes sense

Comment: @RonTheOld i changed the code ( deleted the buttons ) . Be careful just to use `#header1` once in your code. and use preventDefault. as i said in my answer

Comment: Ah perfect it works , however one last problem it does load up the content and does exactly what i want but it opens a new page, again i guess this because of the a tag, is there a way to get rid of this effect?

Comment: @RonTheOld remove `target=_blank` from the `a` tag

Comment: glad i could help. Cheers! :D

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to

```
$("#header2").on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#section_two").fadeToggle(2000);
    $("#section_one").fadeOut(1000);
});
```

and remove duplicate `header1` id in your HTML and `target="_blank"` from the anchor

Answer (score 0):

The id is supposed to be unique so your script runs only for the first occurrence. You could either change your selector to treat id as just another attribute (it would work but I wouldn't do that) or introduce a new attribute to both buttons.

A selector treating id as an attribute would look like this:

```
$("*[id='header1']").click(function() {
  $("#section_one").fadeToggle(2000)
  $("#section_two").fadeOut(1000);
});
```

if you chose to introduce a new attribute to the buttons your html would look like this:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" title="Facebook" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" data-type="produce-content"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>
  <span>facebook</span></a>
</li>
```

and your selector:

```
$("*[data-type='produce-content']").click(function() {
  $("#section_one").fadeToggle(2000)
  $("#section_two").fadeOut(1000);
});
```

The first way would make it easy for you to debug and make sure it works as expected but I would strongly advice against it because id's should be unique.